# How to make a tip showed up while hovering over list item in Vaadin 23

Tags: tooltip, renderer, listitem, vaadin23

I have the following code in my Vaadin application:

```
public class TitleRenderer extends ComponentRenderer<Component, Book> {

@Override
public Component createComponent(Book book) {
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout(createTitleLinkComponent(book));
    layout.getStyle().set("background-color", book.getHighlight());
    Set<Tag> tags = book.getTags();
    if (tags != null && !tags.isEmpty()) {
        ListItem[] tagItems = new ListItem[tags.size()];
        int tn = 0;
        for (Tag tag : tags) {
            ListItem item = new ListItem(tag.getTagName());
            item.addClassName("tag");
            tagItems[tn++] = item;
        }
        UnorderedList tagList = new UnorderedList(tagItems);
        tagList.getStyle().set("list-style-type", "none");
        
        layout.add(tagItems);
    }
    layout.setMinWidth("55%");
    return layout;
}
```

It displays book title and a list of tags associated with the book. However, Tag object contains not only *tagName*, but also *tagDescription*. I'd like to display *tagDescription* when cursor is hovering over *tagName*. Unfortunately, ListItem class does not implement HasToolTip interface.
Can someone, please, help me to create a LitRenderer to do so. I would appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a `Tooltip` even for components that do not implement the `HasTooltip` interface by using the `Tooltip.forComponent` method:

```
        for (Tag tag : tags) {
            ListItem item = new ListItem(tag.getTagName());
            Tooltip tooltip = Tooltip.forComponent(item);
            tooltip.setText(tag.getDescription());
```

Comment: Great. Thanks, I didn't know it. Will try it tonight.